# Shibboleth header attributes not being sent to all pages

Tags: shibboleth

I have the following configuration in Apache in my service provider:

```
<Location /login >
    AuthType Shibboleth
    ShibRequireSession On
    ShibUseHeaders On
    require valid-user
</Location>
```

After authentication, I tried to access the headers in another page, but they did not exist. 
It looks like additional configuration is required in Apache.

How do I configure so that Shibboleth is triggers at /login and yet other pages have access to the headers?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you are using java to fetch shibboleth parameters;

- Shibboleth attributes can only be fetched by `AJP`, So you have to have
  AJP enabled in your server.
- In shibboleth SP's `shibboleth2.xml` file's `ApplicationDefaults` tag add this parameter - `attributePrefix="AJP_"`, this will send parameters as AJP.
- In apache enable `mod_proxy_ajp` module and pass ajp via

  `ProxyPass /my-application/login ajp://localhost:8009/my-application/login`
- Even if this is done, shibboleth parameters won't display directly under `parameters.keySet()`. But if you do `parameters.get(key)` then it will return some value sent by shib.
- Above behaviour may vary for different servers; i.e. you may need to get values by `parameters.get("AJP_"+key)`. P.S. check in both `header` and `request` object.